# HTML inputs not updating after passing asp variable with 6 digits from previous page

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I am trying to pass a variable from one asp web page to another, but when I pass the variable with more then 5 digits it causes my html inputs to not update.

Here is the page where the *variable optionprice* is created

index.asp

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" CodePage=65001 %>

<%
plan = Request("plan")
If plan = "" Then plan = "1"
modelid = Request("modelid")
If modelid = "" Then modelid = "0"
optionprice = Request("optionprice")
If optionprice = "" Then optionprice = "0"
'Responce.Write("optionprice=" & optionprice)

'plan = Request.Form("plan")
'If plan = "" Then plan = "1"
'modelid = Request.Form("modelid")
'If modelid = "" Then modelid = "0"
'Response.Write("plan= " & plan)
'Response.Write("modelid= " & modelid)
dpop = Request.QueryString("dpop")
If dpop = "on" Then dpop = "on"
' Response.Write("dpop= " & dpop)
%>
```

And the result page is 
result_ct.asp

```
optionprice = Request.Form("optionprice")
    If optionprice <> "" Then optionprice = optionprice * 1
    optionprice_2 = optionprice
```

Here is the html form and input

index.asp

```
<form NAME="form1" action="result_ct.asp" method="post" style="margin:0;">
<dl class="downpaymentform">
                <dt>諸費用・オプション代など</dt>
                <dd><div class="input"><input type="text" name="optionprice" maxlength="7" class="blue" value="<%= optionprice %>"><p>円</p></div></dd>
            </dl>
</form>
```

I am banging my head against a wall, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not ASP.NET, this is Classic ASP.

Comment: thanks for the correction

Comment: We need to see the code where you render the `<form>` and `<input />` elements, and are you submitting the form via GET or POST?

Comment: I will add those code blocks

Comment: that was a typo

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?  Have you tried configuring IIS to allow debugging and attached Visual Studio to the w3 process?

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem(see updated question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the issue is probably in this code

```
If optionprice <> "" Then optionprice = optionprice * 1
optionprice_2 = optionprice
```

Rather than this, have the following and use the `CLng` (Convert to long function)

```
If optionprice <> ""
   optionprice_2 = CLng(optionprice)
else
   optionprice_2 = 0
end if
```

If it is a decimal, use `CDbl` instead.

The reason it is failing is that your attempt to cast it to a numeric by multiplying by one, means that you are multiplying it by an integer, so it will be trying to cast it as an integer which has a range of -32,768 to 32,767.  So anything larger than 32,767 will fail.

A long can be integer in the range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

A double is a double-precision, floating-point number in the range -1.79769313486232E308 to -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative values; 4.94065645841247E-324 to 1.79769313486232E308 for positive values.